# Orientation Methods not responding when one view controller view is added as sub view

Tags: iphone, objective-c, addsubview, orientation-changes

I am developing an application in which on my button click I have to show one class controller view as a sub view.
I have added my view Controller as sub view and it works fine.

```
TempViewControlleriPad *tempScreen=[[TempViewControlleriPad alloc]initWithNibName:@"TempViewControlleriPad" bundle:nil];
[self.view addSubview:tempScreen.view];
[tempScreen viewWillAppear:NO];
```

Now when I rotate my device orientation then my sub view did not respond to that orientation means that my sub view did not rotate.

```
TempViewControlleriPad orientation method:-


- (BOOL)shouldAutorotateToInterfaceOrientation:(UIInterfaceOrientation)interfaceOrientation {
    if(interfaceOrientation == UIInterfaceOrientationPortrait || interfaceOrientation == UIInterfaceOrientationPortraitUpsideDown){
             [[NSBundle mainBundle] loadNibNamed:@"TempViewControlleriPad" owner:self options:nil];
    }
    else if(interfaceOrientation == UIInterfaceOrientationLandscapeRight || interfaceOrientation == UIInterfaceOrientationLandscapeLeft){
         [[NSBundle mainBundle] loadNibNamed:@"TempViewControlleriPadLandscape" owner:self options:nil];
    }

    return YES;

}
```

Please suggest me what should I do to solve this orientation problem.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Is the controller of the subview a UIViewController?
You're not supposed to embed a view controller in another one.  From the Apple docs:

> You should not use multiple custom view controllers to manage
> different portions of the same view hierarchy. Similarly, you should
> not use a single custom view controller object to manage multiple
> screens worth of content.
> http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#featuredarticles/ViewControllerPGforiPhoneOS/AboutViewControllers/AboutViewControllers.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40007457-CH112-SW12

You could set the autoresize mask on the subviews.